# Checking a Point Value exists in Array before calling to it

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I'm trying to compare the X value of two points in two different arrays. Problem is sometimes the value I'm comparing may not exist yet and I'm not entirely sure how to go about making this check before I call upon this variable.

My code looks like this

```
if (blueShipPositions[0].x == redShipPositions[0].x) {
            trace("Match in" + blueShipPositions[0]);
        }
```

The x value for any given point in this array tops out at 4 so the error I'm running into looks like this

```
if (blueShipPositions[0].x == redShipPositions[4].x) {
            trace("true");
        }
```

If redShipPositions[4].x does not exist yet I get an error.
I am aware of the IndexOf function, I just don't know how to apply it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it inside an IF statement that determines the size of an array:

```
if (redShipPositions.length >= 5) {
     if (blueShipPositions[0].x == redShipPositions[4].x) {
               trace("true");
     }
}
```

Another way is to have an int local variable to indicate the size of the array:

```
myArraySize = redShipPositions.length;
```

then you can use it as an indicator/(stop point) to safely execute your code w/o the concern of IndexOutOfBound exception.

Answer (score 0):

As answer to your question, take this example : (comments inside)

```
var array:Array = new Array(1, 5, 6, 55)
var index:Number = 3

// type of the elements of array, in this case is Number
var element_type:* = Number

// so to verify if the array[index] exists, we can use

if(array[index]) {

    trace(array[index])

}

// or

if(array[index] != undefined) {

    trace(array[index])

}

// or

if(array[index] != null) {

    trace(array[index])

}

// or

if(typeof array[index] != 'undefined') {

    trace(array[index])

}

// or

if(array[index] is element_type) {

    trace(array[index])

}

// or

if(array[index] as element_type != null) {

    trace(array[index])

}

// or

// here you have to put in the mind that arrays in ActionScript starts always from the index 0, thats why we use < and not <= 
if(index < array.length) {

    trace(array[index])

}

// we use array.indexOf to search an element and not an index
if(array.indexOf(55)){

    trace('we have "55" in this array')

} else {

    trace('we don\'t have "55" in this array')

}
```

For more details about AS3 `Array` object, take a look here : [Adobe.com : AS3 Array](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html).

Hope that helps you.